# How do i generate this java code in php?

Tags: java, php, math

I want to generate this java code in php how do i do that?

Java:

```
Math.round(Math.random()*999999);
```

PHP:

```
 ????
```

Comment: learn PHP -- it's the easiest way for most of the problems you will face in PHP.

Comment: Indeed a simple good search will for sure help you out with such a question.

Answer (score 2):

Read about rand(); - Look at the link, it should give you some more information about it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

But if I may add a side-note, if you searched on the internet for "random function PHP" you would have gotten many results including mine above..

Comment: This should've been a comment

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem it basically is an answer, points to the right direction AKA first hit on Google ;)

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this, since you get a range and Java give floating between 0 and 1.

```
rand(0,999999);
```

Comment: PHP rand return an integer already.